# Convert string to datetime python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to convert my string `start_date='2013-12-01'` to `datetime.date(2013, 12, 1)`.

Was trying to do it like this:

```
datetime.strptime(start_date,'%Y-%M-%d')
```

But it gave me output:

```
datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 0, 12)
```

How can I get an output like `datetime.date(2013, 12, 1)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
>>> datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 1, 0, 0)
```

If you just want a date object:

```
>>> datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
datetime.date(2013, 12, 1)
```

`%M` is minute; `%m` is month; see [the `strptime` docs](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for more information. Note that I'm assuming you've done `from datetime import datetime` or similar here.

Comment: Expected result should in the format as datetime.date(2013, 12, 1)